# Batch file can't find specified path when run from excel hyperlink

Tags: excel, batch-file, network-drive

I have an excel file that has a list of IP addresses and I have linked a batch file that runs a simple ping test and outputs the results to a text log.

When I run the file from the network location it runs no problem. But when I run the excel (Also located in the same directory)...the ping returns "The system cannot find the path specified"

**Note** - It is returning Ping as what cannot be found. Not the file output.

Anything I'm missing?

```
ping -n 1 **EXAMPLE** >> Logs\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_Test.txt
```

[image]

Comment: When you shell out to a command prompt there is no guarantee that the default directory is going to be the one with the Excel workbook running the code. Pass `ThisWorkbook.Path` into the .CMD (or .BAT) file as a parameter and pick it up as `%1`. Alternately, change the default directory at the prompt with `CD` or `CHDIR` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is usually started with the program files directory of Excel as current working directory. Therefore your batch file most likely tries to write the output of **ping** into a subfolder **Logs** in program files directory of Excel which does not exist. Even if there would be a subdirectory **Logs** program files directory of Excel, it would be most likely write-protected. Your batch code should not depend on whatever is the current working directory on starting the batch file.

[Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) posted two of 4 solutions. My answer contains two more with last solution being the easiest if the path to **Logs** directory is fixed.

1. `ThisWorkbook.Path` is passed as parameter with double quotes to batch file and referenced from within the batch file.

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 **EXAMPLE** >>"%~1\Logs\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_Test.txt"
   ```
2. Command `cd` is used in the batch file.

   ```
   cd /D "Path to Logs directory"
   %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 **EXAMPLE** >>%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_Test.txt
   ```
3. Commands `pushd` and `popd` are used in the batch file.

   ```
   pushd "Path to Logs directory"
   %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 **EXAMPLE** >>%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_Test.txt
   popd
   ```

   This solution was provided by [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) and was added here for completeness.
4. The full path and name is specified for the text file in directory **Logs**.

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 **EXAMPLE** >>"Path to Logs directory\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_Test.txt"
   ```

Comment: In your #2, instead of `cd /D "Path to Logs directory"` I'd use rather `pushd "Path to Logs directory"` and add `popd` line under the `...\ping.exe ...` line, regardless of Excel manages it's `ThisWorkbook.Path` independetly on batch session invoked from (and I'm not sure about).